# Using foreach() On An Array Of Size Values With The resizeImage() Function Of Imagick Not Working - PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach, imagick

I have an image I want to re-size to different sizes using the `resizeImage()` function in Imagick.

I'm setting a series of widths in an associative array and then looping through them with a `foreach()` loop.

When I remove the foreach loop and manually add a specific size as the width parameter (e.g. 150) it works, but when I take the values from the associate array with the loop it doesn't?

```
// create new class of image from image in memory/tmp_folder
$image = new Imagick($temp);

$sizesjpeg = [
  'tiny_' => 50,
  'small_' => 150,
  'medium_' => 500,
  'large_' => 1500,
];

$destinationFolder = 'images_lib/';

// image processing of different sizes from the array
foreach ($sizesjpeg as $sizename => $size) {

  // setting the height to 0 means it only resizes the width thus keeping the image ratio
  $image->resizeImage($size, 0, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
  $image->writeImage($destinationFolder . $file);

}
$image->clear();
```

**UPDATE** Having moved the `$image->clear();` method outside of the foreach loop I'm no longer getting an error message, but I'm getting just one image produced that is incredibly blurred and it's the dimensions of the final key in the array (1500px wide).

Comment: So `$size` width and `0` height? Newfangled 1-dimensional images? https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage

Comment: @Sammitch I've no idea what your comment means?

Comment: The first two arguments to `resizeImage()` are the width and the height, and a zero-height image seems absurd.

Comment: @sammitch Setting that property to 0 means it takes the ratio of the image and only resizes the width (the docs are terrible - I saw that in another section)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Imagick, but does `$image->clear();` make an empty object? Maybe that shouldn't be inside the loop. Just guessing.

Comment: @Don'tPanic   It's failing in a different way now I've moved the `$image->clear(); ` method outside of the foreach loop. I'm no longer getting an error message, it's just producing one very blurred image and it's the dimensions of the final key in the array (1500px wide).

Comment: You're not setting `$file` in the loop, so it will either a) always write to the same file (if defined outside the loop) b) always fail to write the file at all (if not defined outside the loop). Based on the update, it's the former. Also, based on your description of the blurred image, the internal buffer of the `Imagick` object is presumably being shrunk to the smallest (50) then expanded successively larger, so either make a new `Imagick` per loop or resize in the opposite order (largest first).

Comment: Hi @msbit That worked ! If you put that as an answer I'll mark it as correct - I'll just add the new full code in a further answer below your one so people can see it for reference

Comment: All good @ap_cornwall, it was just some troubleshooting with fresh eyes.